# How to create a pull request covering multiple files in different directories?

Tags: github, pull-request

I am trying to commit changes to three files `F1`, `F2`, `F3`, in three different directories `D1`, `D2`, `D3`, and create a Pull Request that covers all three changes.

Committing the files is simple enough (and covered by numerous tutorials online). In the GitHub window I navigate to `D1`, and I drag/drop the new version of `F1` over the old. At this point I have a choice of making the changes to the master branch (obviously the wrong choice) or creating a new branch. I choose the latter, naming the branch `B`.

I repeat the navigate/drag/drop process for `D2/F2`... but it won't let me use the same branch name — it automatically appends `-1`. After doing this a third time, I have three branches, `B`, `B-1`, and `B-2`, each containing one change.

When I try to create a Pull Request, it only allows me to specify one branch.

How do I get around this? Is there a way of combining the branches? Or is there a way of updating three files in different directories in one commit?

Comment: Why not use the command line? Why burden yourself with any UI that slows you down? github is nice for reviewing pull requests, but why would one use it to _create_ them? (not saying it is not possible, but when you do *real* development work, rather invest your time learning how to do such things on the command line)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The workflow you want to follow is a little trickier in the UI than it would be if making these changes via the CLI:

1. Make your first file edit, and choose to create your new branch `my-new-branch` via the commit UI:
   [image: creating a new branch via a GitHub UI commit]
2. Navigate back to your repo page, and switch your current branch to `my-new-branch`:
   [image: GitHub branch selector]
3. Make your second file edit, and GitHub will allow you to directly commit to `my-new-branch`:
   [image: Committing to the same branch in GitHub when making a UI edit]
4. Proceed to make your third file edit, again committing to `my-new-branch` like in Step 3.

Once you've completed this set of steps, you should then be able to create a Pull Request of `my-new-branch` back into the main/master branch. All three of your edits should appear in this Pull Request as intended.

Comment: Nice solution within the UI. It works but also an indication that `git` is perhaps the best way to go about this.

Comment: I completely agree - I'd use `git` for this too. The UI solution is now documented in case others need it :)