# Github - Group x2 Commits Into x1 Pull Request

Tags: github

I have made edits to two different files in GitHub.

I want to create one pull request so that the edits to these two files get submitted together under one pull request.

The reason I want to create one pull request is that both changes need to go together in order for the build process to work successfully. Else, it errors out.

How do I do this? Via the GitHub UI, preferably.

Comment: See this answer for the UI method: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67436427/how-to-create-a-pull-request-covering-multiple-files-in-different-directories/67437002#67437002